# Android Check Keyboard typing

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to check the Keyboard typing.
So while writing, no text should be displayed on the TextView!
Only when he finished!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use EditText onFocusChange listener to check if user has done editing:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.youredittext)).setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
/* When focus is lost check that the text field
* has valid values.
*/
  if (!hasFocus) {
   validateInput(v);
  }
}
```

Comment: I use searchView.setOnQueryTextListener

Comment: so take a look at this: https://medium.com/@matdziu/using-rxjava-in-searchview-f1d1d5dcb8b7

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) in your Activity

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Because when a view has acquired focus (like EditText) , it is never guratneed that KeyEvents will be dispatched.